# Why can't TSL offer secure atomic operations for multiple threads

Tags: multithreading, operating-system, thread-safety, test-and-set

Why does using the atomic operating system's system call of TSL doesn't provide us with a thread safe solution for more than two simultaneous threads \ processes?

Edited: I'm sorry for the mistake, I meant TSL and not test-and-set.
Reference to wiki article - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-and-set
Specifically:

> The test-and-set operation can solve the wait-free consensus problem
>   for no more than two concurrent processes.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it would be more appropriate for cs.stackexchange.com

Comment: I'm not familiar with this particular claim. Besides being off topic, do you have a reference for this assertion?